# How do I make an HTML page print in landscape when the user selects 'print'?

Tags: html, printing, landscape, portrait

We generate web pages that should always be printed in landscape mode. Web browser print dialogs default to portrait, so for every print job the user has to manually select landscape. It's minor, but would be nice for the user if we can remove this unnecessary step.

Thanks in advance to all respondents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google indicates that it's not really supported. There's more than a few folks out there trying to [hack](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/showthread.php?t=14877&page=2&highlight=javascript+print+landscape) [their](http://home.tampabay.rr.com/bmerkey/examples/landscape-test.html) way to it - but I'd strongly suggest just rendering a server side PDF instead.

Answer (score 2):

Possible in [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-size-prop) (@page, looks like [Opera only](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css#css2propsprint)) and in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size-prop) which will work [nowhere](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css#css3propsprint). Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The `@page` rule is supposed to allow this, but is only implemented in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do this same thing and found [this](http://edacio.us/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=39) article. It looks particularly "hacky" and as the author points out, may invoke an active x warning in IE. Seems like a losing proposition to confuse the user with an active x warning when they just wanted to print a web page.