# How to print from a ASPX.net website Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crud

Hi guys am starting a self project soon and I need some help, is it possible to print information stored in a SQL database from a visual basic ASPX.net website 2010. I am having problems. I do not have code at the moment as this is my first line of code i want to add I can show u my database structure its only one table:

> prescription ID (PK)
>
> Medication
>
> Patient Name
>
> Illness
>
> Diagnostics
>
> All Health Given

Thank You,

This is not MVC3 this is just Visual Studio 2010 aspx.net

Comment: When you say print data from your database are you meaning to a printer or to display the information on a webpage?

Comment: To a printer so I can click on a button and it send to my printer

Comment: This is a aspx website and not a form

Comment: @user1115496 Assuming the `Print` command in your users' web browser doesn't suffice, see the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231973/238688)

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick search in [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=printing%20in%20asp.net&qs=n&sk=&sc=3-19&form=QBRE) comes up with some examples:

- [Printing in ASP.Net](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Printing-Reporting.aspx)
- [How to Print in ASP.Net 2.0](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92)
- [Creating print preview page dynamically in ASP.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PrintPreview.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(v=VS.100).aspx

Everything you need to know is there.

Comment: -1. Quote: `The System.Drawing.Printing namespace provides print-related services for Windows Forms applications.` This is not Windows Forms, this is WebForms.